# Difference between '..' (double-dot) and '...' (triple-dot) in range generation?

Tags: ruby, syntax, range

I've just started learning Ruby and Ruby on Rails and came across validation code that uses ranges:

```
validates_inclusion_of :age, :in => 21..99
validates_exclusion_of :age, :in => 0...21, :message => "Sorry, you must be over 21"
```

At first I thought the difference was in the inclusion of endpoints, but in the API docs I looked into, it didn't seem to matter whether it was `..` or `...`: it always included the endpoints.

However, I did some testing in irb and it seemed to indicate that `..` includes both endpoints, while `...` only included the lower bound but not the upper one. Is this correct?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

The [documentation for Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Range.html)<sup>†</sup> says this:

> Ranges constructed using `..` run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using `...` exclude the end value.

So `a..b` is like `a <= x <= b`, whereas `a...b` is like `a <= x < b`.

---

Note that, while `to_a` on a Range of integers gives a collection of integers, a Range is *not* a set of values, but simply a pair of start/end values:

```
(1..5).include?(5)           #=> true
(1...5).include?(5)          #=> false

(1..4).include?(4.1)         #=> false
(1...5).include?(4.1)        #=> true
(1..4).to_a == (1...5).to_a  #=> true
(1..4) == (1...5)            #=> false
```

<sup><sup>†</sup>The docs used to not include this, instead requiring reading the [Pickaxe’s section on Ranges](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UE). Thanks to @MarkAmery ([see below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26267693/211563)) for noting this update.</sup>

Comment: Better/less confusing example than the above: `(1..10).include? 10 #=> true` and `(1...10).include? 10 #=> false`

Comment: @timmcliu Though not relevant to illustrating the point that `(a..b) != (a...(b+1))` despite their array representations being equal (when a,b ∈ ℤ). I’ve updated my answer a bit to expand on that.

Comment: If Range is not a set of values, then why does this piece of code treat Range as a set of values:  (1..5).inject {|sum, n| sum + n }

Comment: @ValentinVassilev Range isn’t a set of values, but it can generate them. `inject` comes from [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) which `Range` includes; `Enumerable` utilizes `#each`, which [`Range` implements](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-each). The list generated by `Range#each` is never contained within the `Range` object itself.

Comment: Oof, just the opposite of Swift, D, Rust, C#... ‍♀️. Swift uses `...` for inclusive ranges, Rust uses `..=`, and they all use `..` (except Swift which later changed to `..<`) for half open/end exclusive ranges.

Answer (score 9):

That is correct.

```
1.9.3p0 :005 > (1...10).to_a
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1.9.3p0 :006 > (1..10).to_a
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The triple-dot syntax is less common, but is nicer than `(1..10-1).to_a`

Comment: I think it's really bizarre that *more* dots means the range represents *fewer* values. I guess it's just that `..` is more common and thus less is preferred for it?

Comment: @Andrew: I thought that too, but maybe it's down to the two-dot variety being more commonly desired and thus shorter to type?

Comment: Also, note that `(a..b-1) != (a...b)`, though this answer implies they are.

Comment: (a..b-1) == (a...b) only in the case where a and b are integers and you enumerate the ranges into arrays. Consider the range (1.0...3.5) - what is the value just before 3.5? Certainly not 2.5!

Answer (score 7):

The API docs now describe this behaviour:

> Ranges constructed using `..` run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using `...` exclude the end value.
>
> *-- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Range.html*

In other words:

```
2.1.3 :001 > ('a'...'d').to_a
 => ["a", "b", "c"] 
2.1.3 :002 > ('a'..'d').to_a
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`a...b` *excludes* the end value, while `a..b` *includes* the end value.

When working with integers, `a...b` behaves as `a..b-1`.

```
>> (-1...3).to_a
=> [-1, 0, 1, 2]

>> (-1..2).to_a
=> [-1, 0, 1, 2]

>> (-1..2).to_a == (-1...3).to_a
=> true
```

But really the ranges differ on a [real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_line).

```
>> (-1..2) == (-1...3)
=> false
```

You can see this when incrementing in fractional steps.

```
>> (-1..2).step(0.5).to_a
=> [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]

>> (-1...3).step(0.5).to_a
=> [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5]
```

Comment: Still incorrect after edit. Even if `a` & `b` are integers, the ranges are different. Only when each is converted to an array are they the same. A specific counterexample exists in the accepted answer.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall What I meant to say with that example (but not very well evidently) is on an integer scale it behaves that way. This isn't the case on a more precise fractional scale, as pointed out in your answer. I reckon ranges are most often used on an integer scale though, which is why I believe such an explanation is helpful.

Answer (score -5):

.. and ... denote a range.

Just see it in irb:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :032 > (1...2).each do puts "p" end
p
 => 1...2 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :033 > (1..2).each do puts "p" end
p
p
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, though; both are described to be ranges. *Inclusive* vs *Exclusive* range.