# Is there any difference when defining a range with two dots and three dots in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I tried this in my rails console.

```
2.0.0-p481 :012 > a = 1
 => 1 
2.0.0-p481 :013 > z = 26
 => 26 
2.0.0-p481 :014 > a..z
 => 1..26 
2.0.0-p481 :015 > a...z
 => 1...26
```

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690801/difference-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-range-generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick check:

```
(1..3).to_a
# => [1, 2, 3] 
(1...3).to_a
# => [1, 2]
```

Its evident `...` does not include the last value i.e. its the range till `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the version with two dots includes the last element, the one with three dots does not:

```
(1..4).to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]

(1...4).to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```