# Strip the last path directory from path string in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

Is there an **easy and fast** operation to just strip the last path of a directory of a path in ruby without using regex?

path examples:

```
has="/my/to/somewhere/id"
wants="/my/to/somewhere"
```

Currently I am using:

```
path.split('/')[0...-1].join('/')
```

For `has` I will always know the `id` so I could also use:

```
path.sub("/#{id}", '')
```

**So my question is really, which operation is faster??**

Comment: the array index "-1" is the last element, so you'll get the whole array with [0..-1].  Try `path.split('/')[0..-2].join('/')`  Note also it's two dots, not 3, ie `[0..-2]` not `[0...-2]`

Comment: You can also try `path.delete(path.split("/").last)`

Comment: @MaxWilliams what is the difference? 2 and 3 dots?

Comment: @mahatmanich i thought that the three dot version was just a mistake but turns out it's real and you were using it correctly.  "two dots" returns the last element as well, "three dots" doesn't return the last element.  eg `(0..3).to_a => [0, 1, 2, 3]`, `(0...3).to_a => [0, 1, 2]`, `["a", "b", "c", "d"][0..-1] => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, `["a", "b", "c", "d"][0...-1] => ["a", "b", "c"]`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690801/difference-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-range-generation.  Thanks for helping me discover this.

Comment: @MaxWilliams yeah I wanted to exclude the last el :-) glad we could learn something from each other :-) just found the two dotted :-) and didn't know :D

Comment: The two dotted is much more commonly used, and if you are working with other programmers then the three-dot version could be a bit of a trap for them.  I think a lot of people don't know about the three-dot, it's not very well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Pathname` is a little bit faster than split. On my machine, running a million times:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'pathname'

n = 1000000
id = "id"
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("pathname: ") { n.times { Pathname("/my/to/somewhere/id").dirname.to_s } }
  x.report("split:") { n.times { "/my/to/somewhere/id".split('/')[0...-1].join('/') } }
  x.report("path.sub:") { n.times { "/my/to/somewhere/id".sub("/#{id}", '') } }
end
```

I have got the following results:

```
              user     system      total        real
pathname:   1.550000   0.000000   1.550000 (  1.549925)
split:      1.810000   0.000000   1.810000 (  1.806914)
path.sub:   1.030000   0.000000   1.030000 (  1.030306)
```

Comment: What about path.sub("/#{id}", '') if you know the id?

Comment: @mahatmanich dirname works.. But it is not readable, I always use _parent_. It is like `cd ..`

Comment: Added test for `path.sub("/#{id}", '')`.

Comment: thanks for also showing me how to benchmark @victorkohl

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use [`Pathname#parent`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-parent) method.

```
require 'pathname'

Pathname.new("/my/to/somewhere/id").parent
# => #<Pathname:/my/to/somewhere>
Pathname.new("/my/to/somewhere/id").parent.to_s
# => "/my/to/somewhere"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a method for `Pathname` - [split](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-split), which:

> Returns the dirname and the basename in an Array.

```
require 'pathname'

Pathname.new("/my/to/somewhere/id").split.first.to_s
# => "/my/to/somewhere"
```

Hope that helps!