# defining my_each in terms of my_times

Tags: ruby, iterator, codeblocks, control-flow, ruby-1.9.1

I'm reading *The Well-Grounded Rubyist* and have come across an extra credit challenge to which there is no answer.

```
class Array
  def my_each
    c = 0
    until c == size
      yield(self[c])
      c += 1
    end
    self
  end
end
```

An example is given of creating a `my_each` with `my_times`

```
class Array
  def my_each
    size.my_times do |i|
      yield self[i]
    end
    self
  end
end
```

With the point that many of Ruby's iterators are built on top of `each` and not the other way around.

Given the above `my_each`, how could I use it in an implementation of `my_times`?

To make it clear, an example of a `my_times` implementation was given before:

```
class Integer
  def my_times
    c = 0
    until c == self
      yield(c)
      c += 1
    end
    self
  end
end

5.my_times { |e| puts "The block just got handed #{e}." }
```

So it would seem that the question most certainly implies using `my_each` in an implementation of `my_times`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To implement `my_times` using `my_each`, all you need to do is call `my_each` on an array that looks like `[0, 1, ..., (x - 1)]`, where `x` is `self` (the Integer):

```
class Integer
  def my_times(&block)
    (0...self).to_a.my_each do |n|
      yield n
    end
    self
  end
end
```

P.S. If you defined `my_each` on Enumerable instead of Array (like the "real" `each`), you could remove `to_a` from the third line above and iterate directly over the Range, instead of converting the Range to an Array first.

Comment: Good old ranges. I see what you mean regarding Enumerable. Although the question implicitly forbids it. I will check out your solution. I'm hesitant to accept the answer immediately in case there are any more interesting solutions.

Answer (score 3):

In order to implement my_times we need an array to send my_each message to. At that point of the book I don't think range is covered so I implemented without using a range. Here is the solution:

```
require_relative "my_each"
class Integer
  def my_times
    array = Array.new(self)
    c = 0
    array.my_each do
      array[c] = c
      yield(c)
      c += 1
    end
    self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I just noticed [Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan) used `...` instead of `..` which generates the correct output; See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9690992) for more detail on the difference for ranges. I've updated my answer below.

My account is too new and I can't comment on [Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan)'s solution; I see this was posted about a year ago but I am currently reading through *The Well-Grounded Rubyist* and wanted to comment on the solution.

I had approached it <s>the same</s> *in a similar* way as Jordan <s>but found that the output is off compared to</s>; *The Well-Grounded Rubyist* implementation of `my_times` <s>which</s> produces:

```
puts 5.my_times { |i| puts "I'm on iteration # {i}!" }
I'm on iteration 0!
I'm on iteration 1!
I'm on iteration 2!
I'm on iteration 3!
I'm on iteration 4!
```

<s>Jordan's solution outputs:</s>

```
puts 5.my_times { |i| puts "I'm on iteration # {i}!" }
I'm on iteration 0!
I'm on iteration 1!
I'm on iteration 2!
I'm on iteration 3!
I'm on iteration 4!
I'm on iteration 5!
```

I used a magic number to match *The Well-Grounded Rubyist* output **[See Jordan's solution, using `...` instead of `..` which removes the need for the magic number]**

```
class Integer
  def my_times
    (0..(self-1)).to_a.my_each do |n|
      yield n
    end
    self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I shortened dwyd's implementation to supply a block rather than using the do..end.

```
class Integer
  def my_times
    (0...self).to_a.my_each { |i| yield i }
  end
end
```

Also, I don't think you need to do `self-1`.