# How can I do this inside the each_char?

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
sentence.each_char {|char|
   ......
   ......
}
```

I want this:

```
sentence.each_char {|char|
   if (char is the last char)
     ......
   end
}
```

Does anybody know how I can do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241684/magic-first-and-last-indicator-in-a-loop-in-ruby-rails for plenty of good ideas.  There's no simple, idiomatic way, and the best alternative depends on specifics of your use case.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
length = sentence.length
sentence.each_char.with_index(1){|char, i|
  if i == length
    ...
  end
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You are looking for 'with_index' option

```
sentence.each_char.with_index {|char, index|
  if (index == sentence.length-1)
   ......
  end
}
```