# Exclude last element in a loop

Tags: c#, loops

I have a loop in my app. Code is following :-

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    ColorNames +=dr["ColorName"].ToString() + "\n";
```

But i don't want to add `\n` at the last `Datarow`. Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifying last loop when using for each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068110/identifying-last-loop-when-using-for-each)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreach do not work on index.

**Option 1: ForEach Loop**

Use foreach loop. Loop till last and outside loop do like

```
ColorNames.Substring(0, ColorNames.Length-1);
```

**Option 2: For Loop**

Use for loop and check for index inside loop for all indexes till last. add \n  and in last index do not add \n

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   ColorNames += i < dt.Rows.Count-1 
           ? dr["ColorName"].ToString() + "\n"
           : dr["ColorName"].ToString();
}
```

**OR**

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   ColorNames += dr["ColorName"].ToString() + (i < dt.Rows.Count-1 ?  "\n": "");
```

**Option 3: LINQ**

```
ColorNames = String.Join("\n", dt.Rows.Select(dr => dr["ColorName"].ToString()));
```

Comment: Option 3 copy & pasted from lazyberezovsky's answer?

Comment: @Nikhil, Option 2 seems great.

Comment: @No. I copied & pasted it from my brain. Its common practice that `DataRow` variable is taken as `dr` just as `DataTable` variable is taken as `dt`.

Answer (score 8):

```
ColorNames = String.Join("\n", dt.Rows.Select(dr => dr["ColorName"].ToString()));
```

Here is updated version (forgot that cast to Enumerable needed):

```
ColorNames = String.Join("\n", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("ColorName")));
```

Comment: +1, but: you need `+=` instead of `=` to mimic the original code behaviour.

Comment: For reference, in .NET 4 onwards you can pass in an IEnumerable, so you don't need the overhead of creating an array.

Comment: @Vlad: You don't. You assign the result of String.Join to ColorNames.

Comment: @VVS: Not quite. Imagine that `ColorNames` was non-empty before the beginning of the code.

Comment: @Vlad if it was not empty, then you are right `+=` should be used. But I think assignment is what he needs

Answer (score 0):

```
var colorNamesList = dt.Rows
  .Cast<DataRow>()
  .Select(dr => dr["ColorName"].ToString())
  .ToArray();

var colorNames = String.Join("\n", colorNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    count++;
    ColorNames +=dr["ColorName"].ToString();
    if (count < dt.Rows.Count)
        ColorNames += "\n";
}
```